# Add delay to javascript after button click

Tags: javascript

I have this bit of script to reload a div on a click - which works for what I need it to do.

I want to add a delay to the reload of say 1-2 seconds with a load icon before it loads. I looked at setTimeout but I don't know where to put it.

https://codepen.io/jameswill77/pen/vYRpxVV

```
<a href="" id="something">click</a>


    <div id="mydiv">
    
    //content
    
    </div>
        </div>

setTimeout(function(){

$('#something').link(function() {
    $("#mydiv").reload();
});
}, 10000);
```

Comment: how about adding the script on the button click event.

Comment: try  this function like 
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Stuff be done'); //This will be delayed for one second
}, 1000);
and call it on button click event. and put you code inside this function.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you.

```
<a href="#" id="something">click</a>
<div id="mydiv">
    //content
</div>

<script>
    $( '#something' ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // code before reload
        
        setTimeout( function () {
            $( "#mydiv" ).reload();
        }, 2000 ); // time in millisecond
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it, but I didn't get the delay, I've added in the script inside the DIV so you can see what I'm trying to reload

<a id="something" href="">click</a>
<div id="mydiv">

<div class="calculator" data-calc-id="ogNjyteRSgnEHv6Ps" data-type="framed"></div>
<script src="https://scripts.convertcalculator.com/embed.js"></script>


</div>